# FragmentManager is always null

Tags: android, android-fragments, oncreate, fragmentmanager

so this one really has me stumped. I am trying to create a simple ViewPager activity which has three swipe views containing a listview. I have a FragmentPagerAdapter, a ListFragment set to hold the listviews, and have defined the layout for the fragments. Here is my problem is that FragmentPagerAdapter takes a FragmentManager, so I try to pass it in like so

```
mFragmentPagerAdapter=new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
```

but the FragmentManager is always null, meaning that the rest of the work to set up the pager crashes the app

I have no idea why getSupportFragmentManager would return null.

Here is the code for my activity, or at least the relevant bits

```
public class JobListActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private ArrayList<Job> jobsQuote=new ArrayList<Job>();
private ArrayList<Job> jobsIn= new ArrayList<Job>();
private ArrayList<Job> jobsOut=new ArrayList<Job>();


private ListFragment quoteListFragment=new ListFragment();
private ListFragment inListFragment =new ListFragment();
private ListFragment outListFragment=new ListFragment();


JobFragmentPagerAdapter mFragmentPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_job_list);
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mFragmentPagerAdapter =
            new JobFragmentPagerAdapter(fm);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.jobs_view_pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mFragmentPagerAdapter);
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide, thanks so much for your time

Here is the tutorial I have been following from the android developer web site

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

clearly I am missing something.

Comment: your activity extends FragmentActivity from support library?

Comment: yes, sorry I should have mentioned that

Comment: Why don't you use it the same way as it is in tutorial ?
Dont set `FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();`, but try directly givint it in.

Comment: Simply an attempt at something different, same null if i follow the tutorial exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. When I implement the methods from Fragment activity, I accidentily overrode getSupportFragmentManager(); to return null.